# Puppet: Could not find resource 'File[/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml]' in parameter 'require'

Tags: puppet

I'm using Puppet to replace Spacewalk Configuration Channels.
I'm very new to puppet, and the class I'm writing should copy some files to the host system.
I have this in my class:

```
class main_configurations {
  file { '/etc/auditbeat':
    ensure  => directory,
    path    => '/etc/auditbeat',
    require => File['/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml'],
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/main_configurations/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml',
    recurse => true,
  }
}
```

But when I run puppet agent -t I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Could not find resource 'File[/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml]' in parameter 'require' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/main_configurations/manifests/init.pp, line: 8) on node <servername>
```

For completeness, this is the folder structure on my puppet server:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/main_configurations/files/auditbeat
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/main_configurations/files/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/main_configurations/files/auditbeat/audit.rules.d
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/main_configurations/files/auditbeat/audit.rules.d/auditbeat-rules.conf
```

Comment: The error message states that there is no file resource with a namevar `/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml` in your compiled catalog. You would need to check why that resource is not being included in the catalog.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I thought that puppet would be so smart to copy "auditbeat.yml" from puppet:///modules/main_conf......

Comment: @mlazzarotto91, Puppet tries not to make assumptions about what manifest authors mean.  Given its primary area of application, getting such an assumption wrong could have devasting effects.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Manage the single file `/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml` or (with one resource) manage a whole collection of files in `/etc/auditbeat`?  Or something else?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm trying to copy recursively the `auditbeat` folder from the server.
Please let me know of other methods to copy multiple files and creating directories without too much boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I run puppet agent -t I get the following error:
>
> > Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on
> > SERVER: Server Error: Could not find resource
> > 'File[/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml]' in parameter 'require' (file:
> > /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/main_configurations/manifests/init.pp,
> > line: 8) on node

As @MattSchuchard explained in comments, that means exactly what it says: you have a `require` parameter that refers to resource `File[/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml]`, but that (Puppet) resource is not declared in any of the manifest files that were processed.  This constitutes an inconsistency in your manifest set. It has nothing to do with which files are available for installation from your module or which are already present on the target, nor about what Puppet might do when given a manifest set free of such inconsistencies.

**Considering the declaration that *is* presented:**

> ```
>   file { '/etc/auditbeat':
>     ensure  => directory,
>     path    => '/etc/auditbeat',
>     require => File['/etc/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml'],
>     source  => 'puppet:///modules/main_configurations/auditbeat/auditbeat.yml',
>     recurse => true,
>   }
> ```

I'm inclined to think that you misunderstand at least what the `require` metaparameter means.  It is one of several that speak to the *relative order* in which various resources are applied.  It says that application of the resource being declared requires the specified other resources to have successfully been applied before.  That's surely not what you intend here.

Moreover, a resource reference such as you are assigning to that parameter does not serve as a resource declaration. It does not contain enough information to do so.  As the name suggests, it is a *reference* to a resource declared elsewhere.

It looks like you are trying to manage a subdirectory tree rooted at `/etc/auditbeat` to match a tree in your module.  In that case, you probably want something more like this:

```
  file { '/etc/auditbeat':
    # no path required if it is already given by the resource title
    ensure  => 'directory',
    source  => 'puppet:///modules/main_configurations/auditbeat',
    recurse => true,
  }
```

Mainly, that drops the `require` parameter.

Note that that combination will also enable purging for the destination subtree, so that unmanaged non-directories anywhere within are removed.  If you don't want that then use `recurse => 'remote'` instead.

There is a variety of other attributes that you might want to add, mostly to do with ownership and mode for the installed files.  If you just want to copy some or all of that from the files on the server then you will want to add `source_permissions => 'use'`.  Alternatively, there are attributes for explicitly specifying ownership and mode in your manifest.